# JSON parameter of function in IE8

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-8

So for a certain reason, I need to override a function. The thing is that I can't make it work this function in IE8:

```js
function myFunction(param)
{
 alert(param.text);
}
```

I've tested in Chrome and it works:

```js
myFunction({text:"hello"});
```

But it doesn't on IE8. It says **"Object Expected"**.

What's going on?

Comment: There's no JSON there. That's a JavaScript object.

Comment: You've split your live demo across two snippets, so neither of them do anything. That doesn't do a good job of demonstrating the problem.

Comment: But then, why it's working on Chrome?

Comment: It isn't. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOiCeJwXihAZL2rX1pJwUkokM8ehHeXFP8

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because you haven't quoted the property name, try this:

```
myFunction({"text":"hello"});
```

Comment: Not even obscure Internet Explorer bugs make `text` a reserved word.